# LWC Template saying object array undefined

Tags: javascript, rest-api, lightning-web-components, json, html

I am trying to produce a LWC that displays a custom data that I get through a series of steps, but is saying that the objects in the array are undefined and I cannot pass them into the template.

**Steps:**

1. I call an apex method that returns a list of unique strings
2. That list of strings is then passed into a utility js method that makes a fetch call for each item, creates a js object, and pushes that object into an array

```
export default function getFullResources(titles){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        let resources = [];

        titles.forEach(element => {
            titleAPICall(element)
            .then((item)=>{
                resources.push(item);
            })
        });
        console.log(resources)
        resolve(resources)
    })
}

async function titleAPICall(title){
    var callURL = ""
    return fetch(callURL, {
        'method': 'GET'
    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((txt)=>{ 
        console.log(txt)
        return {title: String(txt.value[0].Title),shortsummary: String(txt.value[0].shortsummary),dateCreated: String(txt.value[0].DateCreated),URL: String("" + title),};  
    }); 
}
```

3. The results are then stored into my variable that is being used in the html template

**LWC JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getRecentResources from '@salesforce/apex/ResourceInteractionController.getRecentResources';
import getFullResources from 'c/utils';

export default class ResourceDashboardRecentlyInteracted extends LightningElement {
    @track resources = [];

    connectedCallback(){
        getRecentResources()
        .then((result) => getFullResources(result))
        .then((out) => {
            this.resources = out;
            console.log(this.resources);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading Resources',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        })
    }
}
```

**LWC HTML**

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <template if:true={resources} for:each={resources} for:item="resource">
          <li key={resource}>
            {resource.data.title}, {resource.data.dateCreated}, {resource.data.shortsummary}, {resource.data.URL}
          </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

**Console.log outputs:**

- LWC JS: `console.log(resources)` - proper array
- Utility JS: `console.log(this.resources)` - proper array, `console.log(this.resources[0])` - undefined

I believe my issue is with my HTML template, the JS object creation, or both.  But I am not sure.  Having been fighting with the bug for a few days now, any insight would be appreciated!!

**Edit - Image of resources & this.resources console.log call:**
[image: console.log]

Comment: can you show what is inside resources?

Comment: @User6670 Edited post and added screenshot

Comment: Don't you need to write your getFullResources to return a promise, not an array, that resolves to your array once all the details have been fetched? Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: @PhilW Changing getFullResources to be wrapped inside a new Promise, with the resolve being the array, provided the same result as without the promise return.

Comment: Just noticed that resources is marked (at)api. This is inappropriate. It should be (at)tracked. A component isn't permitted to update its API properties.

Comment: @PhilW Left the promise change, and changed resources to being (at)track.  The console.log result is the same as posted, but now inside of a [Proxy label](https://i.imgur.com/dkiwcDi.png) .  The call to resources[0] still gives undefined - shown in last line

Comment: Perhaps you could post your updated promise change by editing the question?

Comment: @PhilW Edited post to show changes